# Phantomjs Get link href and its childs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Im trying to get of list of elements an link href and their img src from a webpage with phantomjs.

Example of the webpage:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="link A">
        <img src="link B"></img>
      </a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

I tried:

```
 var lis = page.evaluate(function() {
         var link_img = new Array;
         SrcAlt = [];
         var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

         for(q = 0; q < li.length; q++){

           var a = li[q].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];


            var link = a.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];


            SrcAlt.push({"img": a.href, "link": link.src});

    }
    return SrcAlt;
});
```

It just return "img": a.href correct, I cant get "link", I dont know why. How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extract image's `src` attribute, like you did with `a.href`:

```
SrcAlt.push({"img": a.href, "link": link.src});
```

**Update**

To confirm the validity of the answer I ran a test script against a test webpage.

The webpage:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="http://google.com">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></img>
              </a>
           </li>
         </ul>    
    </body>
</html>
```

The script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost/phantomjs.php', function(status) {

    var lis = page.evaluate(function() {
        var link_img = SrcAlt = new Array;

        var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

        for(q = 0; q < li.length; q++){

            var a = li[q].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

            var link = a.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

            SrcAlt.push({"img": a.href, "link": link.src});

        }
        return (SrcAlt);
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(lis));
    phantom.exit();   
});
```

The result:

```
[{"img":"http://google.com/","link":"https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"}]
```

If the answer's still not working for you, please show us your script, your actual web page code, the results of script run, what version PhantomJS is - we'll try to find out what's wrong.